# What does the double slash(transition 0 --> 1) mean in SRAM datasheet?

Tags: fpga, digital-logic

The following image is from [the datasheet of SRAM IS64WV51216BLL](https://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/61-64WV51216.pdf)(page 15).

It is a SRAM's write timing diagram.I don't know the meaning of double transitions for `WE` signal.I have circled it in red.

[SRAM write timing diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjQOW.png)

> [Timing Diagram Basics](https://rheingoldheavy.com/timing-diagram-basics/)

> [Understanding Timing diagrams of digital systems](https://scienceprog.com/understanding-timing-diagrams-of-digital-systems/)

> [How to Read Timing Diagrams: A Maker’s Guide](https://maker.pro/custom/tutorial/how-to-read-timing-diagrams-a-makers-guide)

Acturally I have searched many material,but nothing I wanted.Please help me!Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not multiple transitions, rather it is a timing window where the transition can happen which is bounded by two timing constraints: **t<sub>SA</sub>** and **t<sub>PWE</sub>**.

**t<sub>SA</sub>** is the ***A**ddress* ***S**etup* time which is the *earliest* that **W̄** can be asserted. **t<sub>PWE</sub>** is the *latest* **W̄** can be asserted and not violate the ***P**ulse* ***W**idth*.